# AngularJS Directive Template for Select and Ng-Options

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am having trouble trying to turn the following html snippets into equivalent templates in a pair of directives.

```
<select ng-model="address.country" ng-change="address.division=null"
        ng-options="countryId as countryDetails.label for (countryId, countryDetails) in countries"></select>
<select ng-model="address.province" 
        ng-options="divisionId as divisionDetails.label for (divisionId, divisionDetails) in countries[address.country]['divisions']"></select>
```

The countries variable has the following structure:

```
countries = {
    "": {
        label: "",
        divisions: {
            "": {label: ""}
        }
    },
    "Canada": {
        label: "Canada",
        divisions: {
            "": {label: ""},
            "Alberta": {label: "Alberta"},
            "British Columbia": {label: "British Columbia"},
            etc . . .
        }
    },
    "United States": {
        label: "United States",
        divisions: {
            "": {label: ""},
            "Alabama": {label: "Alabama"},
            "Alaska": {label: "Alaska"},
            etc . . .
        }
};
```

Using the following as a template in my directive created a drop-down list, but it had no values in it.  The list of countries is defined in the javascript file where the directives are a global var and country is defined in the directive scope to be the string value of the matching attribute.

```
template: '<select ng-options="divisionId as divisionDetails.label for (divisionId, divisionDetails) in countries[{{country}}]['divisions']" ></select>',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `ng-repeat` key + value.

**HTML**

```
<select ng-model="selectedmodel">
    <option ng-repeat="(key,val) in countries">{{val.label}}</option>
</select>  

<select >
    <option ng-repeat="(key,val) in countries[selectedmodel].divisions">{{val.label}}</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.countries = {
    "Hartabarta": {
        label: "Hartabarta",
        divisions: {
            "": {label: ""}
        }
    },
    "Canada": {
        label: "Canada",
        divisions: {
            "": {label: ""},
            "Alberta": {label: "Alberta"},
            "British Columbia": {label: "British Columbia"}           
        }
    },
    "United States": {
        label: "United States",
        divisions: {
            "": {label: ""},
            "Alabama": {label: "Alabama"},
            "Alaska": {label: "Alaska"}            
        }
    }
};

$scope.selectedmodel = 'Canada';
```

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nF7eJ/49/)**</kbd>

Hope this is what you want.

Comment: Because these drop-down lists will be used in various places in my project, it needs to be self-contained.  My hope is to use '<country-list ng-model="myCountry" division="myDivision></country-list>' and '<division-list ng-model="myDivision" country="myCountry"></division-list>' to access the list.

Comment: My team wants to use a directive instead of a controller.  They insist it is possible to get these chained lists without requiring an additional ng-controller in order to use them.

Comment: Well, put it as template into directive, I don't see a problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a filter

```
"ng-options" => "model as (model | modelAsSelectOption) for model in collection"

.filter 'modelAsSelectOption', ->
  return (model) ->
    "#{model.name} - #{model.type} (#{model.otherinfo})"
```

I'd prefer a template for the options too, but, this does the trick.